# Efficiently change a key of a Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking to replace the keys of a `dict` to shorter variants so that it can be sent across the wire in a compact form. Is there a way to updating a key, rather than creating a new item in in the `dict` and deleting the old?

What I'm doing now:

```
>>> a = dict(long_key=None)
>>> a['l'] = a['long_key']
>>> del a['long_key']
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
>>> a = dict(long_key=None)
>>> a.update_key('long_key', 'l')
```

I'm unsure of `dict`'s internals. However, it seems that something like  `update_key` might be able to avoid needing to delete the old key.

Comment: are you looking for space efficiency, time efficiency, or code elegance?

Comment: Compressing your transport is probably a saner solution than obfuscating your data.

Comment: Just to respond to criticisms about the approach- I asked the question because I'm interested in learning about how the Python `dict` works. These tiny snippets don't represent the whole of what I'm doing, they just serve to demonstrate my intentions to make the question clearer. Downvoting a Q on the basis that you don't like its subject matter is a bit petty. Questions should be downvoted because they're unclear or vague.

Comment: @Claudiu- For this part of the code, time efficiency.

Comment: For more info about the `dict` implementation in CPython see some of the references here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more elegant solution might be to create a new dictionary... essentially make a slightly different shallow copy:

```
a_send = dict((k[0], v) for k,v in a.items())
```

That will certainly be less space-efficient, though - are you looking for space efficiency, time efficiency, or code elegance?

Comment: Marking as accepted as some form of generator expression is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 3):

That's premature optimization. If you really want to save bandwidth, do it by either compressing the data [normally](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/DataCompression.html) or use simpler data structures.

Answer (score 1):

How many times do you need to send it? Maybe instead of changing anything, you can just process the keys as you go?

Instead of doing something like (guessing pseudo-code):

```
short_dict = shorten_keys(long_dict)
for k,v in short_dict:
    send_over(k,v)
```

do something like:

```
for k,v in long_dict:
    send_over(shorten(k),v)
```

If you have to send it many times, you can also create a map of long -> short keys and use it while sending. Wasting space / time to create copies might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
longer = dict(long_key=None)
mapping = dict(long_key='l')
shorter = dict((mapping[k], v) for k,v in longer.iteritems())
```