# python dictionaries search complexity compared to java hashmap/hashtable

Tags: java, python, hash, dictionary, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are Python’s Built In Dictionaries Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented)

I am fairly new to python and have a background in java. I was wondering whether the dictionary in python has the same search complexity as for hash maps in java. Example: searching for a key in a hash table/map in java is a constant time operation, I was wondering whether searching for a key in a dictionary in python is also a constant time operation. I have read through a few pages of python documentation regarding mapping but it doesn't seem to indicate any hashing of keys of dictionary in python so I was wondering whether:

1. searching keys in a dictionary in python was constant time operation.
2. If so how do they achieve this constant time search without hashing?

Comment: What made you so sure that `dict` wasn't based on a hash table in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries have O(1) search complexity.

See the [Time complexity wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Python dictionaries are implemented as a hash table, and keys are hashed; you can influence the hashing by implementing a [`__hash__` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__).

Comment: And the OPs point 2 would be redundant

Comment: do you know if they achieve this by hashing the keys in the dictionaries or by some other method? I would really appreciate some input regarding this matter.