# Python hashing algorithm in default dict

Tags: python, algorithm

Simple question.

What hashing algorithm is used in python's default dict?

```
>>> g = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3 }
>>> g
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> g.keys()
['a', 'c', 'b']
>>>
```

I expected `['a','b','c']` on `g.keys()`
Linear probe (guess not)? double hash?

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c might contain something relevant.

Comment: Any hashing is size dependent. And the char/string hash is used. This should not be surprising.

Comment: @riamse That code is well commented.

Comment: It's impossible to know what the "order" will be without knowing the hash function, the bucket count at each insertion, the collision resolution, and the order of insertion .. at the very least. The linked source code says how a particular implementation does it. These same "unpredictable results" can be achieved through chaining, probing, double hashing, and extensible hashing - that is, the result is a compound factor and not directly related to the collision resolution.

Comment: Why did you expect a, b, c, knowing it was a hash? Linear probe is frowned upon.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that Python will use any particular method - different implementations could use any one they wish. `dict`s are unordered, so it doesn't matter how it's implemented (provided it fulfills certain obligations).

As to how [CPython does it...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022835/722121)