# How do standard libraries implement hash tables in practice?

Tags: java, c++, python, hash, language-agnostic

Some programming languages such as python, Java and C++11 have hash tables (although sometimes under different names with extended functionality) as part of their standard library. I would like to understand from a high level algorithmic point of view what has been implemented. Specifically:

- What function of the keys is used to give the location to place the data (i.e. what is the hash function that is used)?
- Which algorithms do they use for resolving collisions? As an example, do any of them use [simple chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_linked_lists)?
- Is there any use of randomness to pick the hash functions?

Comment: Can't you just look at an open source implementation?

Comment: If this is language agnostic, why to tag with Java, C++ and python?

Comment: This is very broad. The answers will be different for different languages. For example, I'm fairly sure Python uses open addressing, but Java (according to Peter Lawrey below) uses simple chaining. You seem to be asking for a generalization: "how do modern programming languages implement hash tables, in general." But no generalization can be made. I would suggest focusing on one language (but check for dupes first).

Comment: There's a python-specific answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented).

Comment: @senderle I was really looking for a list rather than any generalization.  I was hoping there might be a "big list" tag but I couldn't find one.

Comment: In Haskell they don't even use hashes.

Comment: @CarlNorum:  I doubt anybody could come to any true understanding of the theories behind hash tables by simply reading the source code implementation of one.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac, haskell `Map`s don't use hashes, but there is at least one `HashTable` implementation (see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.1.0/doc/html/Data-HashTable.html)). I'm pretty sure it uses hashes.

Comment: For anyone interested: this seems like a relevant blog post https://rcoh.me/posts/hash-map-analysis/

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn That’s a nice link but there is no mention of randomisation which I thought was an important part of modern implementations.

Answer (score 2):

For Java,

> How are the hash functions themselves computed?

They are implemented by the class itself with `int hashCode()`

> Which algorithms do they use for resolving collisions? As an example, do any of them use simple chaining?

Typically simple chaining.  Java 8 will support trees for collisions of String.

> Is there any use of randomness to pick the hash functions?

No, except for String elements/keys to avoid DOS attacks.

Comment: Thank you. What is the mathematical function that is being computed to give the location to place the data? What I mean by this is that if the key is x, say, then one option might a*x +b mod p mod m where p is a large prime, a and b are between 0 and p-1 and m is the size of the table.

Comment: @Raphael It doesn't use a prime number as `%` is expensive.  Instead it uses this function `h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);` and then takes the lowest bits. i.e. a mask.

Comment: @Raphael You might find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032197/are-there-different-ways-to-calculate-the-table-index-in-hashmap/