# Are there different ways to calculate the table index in HashMap

Tags: java

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

I was looking at the wiki and here are the steps to find the table index.

```
hash = hashfunc(key) // calculate hash value.
index = hash % array_size // calculate index value through modulus.
```

But it seems the way it is performed in Java is quite different.

```
static int hash(int h) {
   h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
   return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}

static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
   return h & (length-1);
}
```

The indexFor method which calculates the table index seems to be different. Can anyone add some light on this.

**Update:**

Hashing algorithim might vary accordingly, but the way we calculate the table index should be even if i am not wrong, but i see a conflict in what wiki does and the way java does?.

**Sample code to test:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put("Shane", null);
        Iterator<String> itr = m.keySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = itr.next();
            int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
            System.out.println("&&& used" + "table[" + (hash & 15) + "]=" + key);
            System.out.println("%%% used" + "table[" + (hash % 15) + "]=" + key);
        }
    }

    static int hash(int h) {
        h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
        return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
    }   

}
```

**Output:**

```
&&& usedtable[14]=Shane
%%% usedtable[8]=Shane
```

Run the above program and you could see the table index is different when i use % and table index is different when i use &.

Comment: What's your exact question? The formula you see in wikipedia is just **one way** to detect a hash key/index. It is not meant to be always like that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: it seems the one in wiki and one in java code is different for calculating the table index.

Comment: And the problem is...

Comment: From the link in wikipedia, looks like you forgot to read this part (emphasys mine): ***Often** this is done in two steps: <formulas you posted in question>*. Note: Java hash falls in the not often part :).

Comment: Note my last comment.

Comment: One more thing. You're just reviewing the Java code from OpenJDK or probably from HotSpot, other JVM implementations like JRockit or IBM JVM may use a totally different implementation.

Comment: Its not clear, my question is you have the hash value... why are there two different methods to calculate the table index... the one with & produces different result compared to % operator.

Comment: @Shane The table size of hash maps will always be a power of two, so `&` can be used instead of `%`.

Comment: Again, what is the real problem with this? If is plain curiosity, do not ask us, instead one of the Java SE core programmers instead. Also, from the given link in wikipedia you can reach a [list of hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions), where you can find some of them do not use modulus operator, for example [BSD checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_checksum) (the first on the list).

Comment: @arshajii: why is the wiki using % instead of &, in any case the array size would be power of 2 for hashmap and the max would be 2 power of 30...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I am sorry if my replies were not clear, it seems i am missing some points of understanding on calculating the table index.... that's why i raised this question... i have updated my code with sample test code to check.

Comment: What is your question? Just ask a single, clear question that states what you don't understand.

Comment: @codethulhu: i don't understand on why the table index is different when we use & and %, it should be the same... that's what peter has also answered below....

Comment: One is getting the modulus of the division operation, the other is using a bitwise operator to create a "unique" key for the hashcode in the length of the backing array. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But it seems the way it is performed in Java is quite different.

Actually they are exactly the same.

```
hash = hashfunc(key) // calculate hash value.
```

is the same as

```
hash = hash(key.hashCode());
```

and

```
index = hash % array_size       (assumes the hash is unsigned)
```

is the same as

```
return h & (length-1);
```

as the length is a power of 2.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have updated my question with the sample test code... can you explain on that regard.

Comment: @Shane Note the `(length -1)` where length is a power of 2. ;)  i.e. you need to compare `hash & 15` with `hash % 16`