# How Python dict stores key, value when collision occurs?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

How Python stores the dict key, values when collision occurs in hash table? Whats the hash algorithm used to get the hash value here?

Comment: The answer depends on the [implementation of Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations) we are talking about :)

Comment: Hi thefourtheye, i need the details for CPython

Answer (score 77):

For the "normal" Python, [this great writeup](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/02/how-hash-collisions-are-resolved-in.html) by Praveen Gollakota explains it very well, here are the important bits:

- Python dictionaries are implemented as hash tables. Hash tables consist of slots, and keys are mapped to the slots via a hashing function.
- Hash table implementations must allow for hash collisions i.e. even if two keys have same hash value, the implementation of the table must have a strategy to insert and retrieve the key and value pairs unambiguously.
- Python dict uses open addressing to resolve hash collisions (see [dictobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c):296-297).
- In open addressing, hash collisions are resolved by probing (explained below) .
- The hash table is just a contiguous block of memory (like an array, so you can do `O(1)` lookup by index).
- Each slot in the hash table can store one and only one entry. This is important.
- Each entry in the table actually a combination of the three items - `<hash, key, value>`. This is implemented as a C struct (see [dictobject.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Include/dictobject.h):51-56).
- When a new dict is initialized, it starts with 8 slots. (see [dictobject.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Include/dictobject.h):49)
- When adding entries to the table, we start with some slot, `i` that is based on the hash of the key. CPython uses initial `i = hash(key) & mask`, where `mask = PyDictMINSIZE - 1`, but that's not really important. Just note that the initial slot, `i`, that is checked depends on the hash of the key.
- If that slot is empty, the entry is added to the slot (by entry, I mean, `<hash|key|value>`). But what if that slot is occupied!? Most likely because another entry has the same hash (hash collision!)
- If the slot is occupied, CPython (and even PyPy) compares the hash and the key (by compare I mean == comparison not the *is* comparison) of the entry in the slot against the key of the current entry to be inserted ([dictobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c)337,344-345). If both match, then it thinks the entry already exists, gives up and moves on to the next entry to be inserted. If either hash or the key don't match, it starts probing.
- Probing just means it searches the slots by slot to find an empty slot. Technically we could just go one by one, `i+1`, `i+2`, ... and use the first available one (that's linear probing). But for reasons explained beautifully in the comments (see [dictobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c):33-126), CPython uses random probing. In random probing, the next slot is picked in a pseudo random order. The entry is added to the first empty slot. For this discussion, the actual algorithm used to pick the next slot is not really important (see [dictobject.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c):33-126 for the algorithm for probing). What is important is that the slots are probed until first empty slot is found.
- The same thing happens for lookups, just starts with the initial slot `i` (where `i` depends on the hash of the key). If the hash and the key both don't match the entry in the slot, it starts probing, until it finds a slot with a match. If all slots are exhausted, it reports a fail.
- To avoid slowing down lookups, the dict will be resized when it is two-thirds full (see [dictobject.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Include/dictobject.h):64-65).

Comment: This is a really good writeup.

Comment: I'd give +10 if I could.  Very well summarized in layman's terms

Comment: Loved it. It's no less then a well articulated blog. Please share if you write technical blogs.

Comment: You said: If both match, then it thinks the entry already exists, gives up and moves on to the next entry to be inserted.

But what about comparing values? If the values are the same, does it just skip that operation or create a new object in memory and update the reference in the hashtable? What about if the values differ? Does it just create a new object in memory and change the reference to the new object in the hashtable?

Answer (score 1):

The short version: The Python spec doesn't specify a dictionary implementation, but CPython uses a hash map and handles collisions with open addressing.

See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9022835/471671) and also the [Wikipedia page on hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing).