# Iterating over dictionary returns keys in sorted order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question about how python handle data in dictionaries. Lets say I have a simple dictionary with a number as the key and a number as the value as shown below:

```
a = { 5: 3, 20: 1, 1: 1, 5: 2, 100: 3, 11: 6,
     14: 1, 15: 2, 16: 4, 17: 2, 25: 1, 19: 1 }
```

I want to iterate through this dictionary and print out the keys. Every time I loop through the dictionary (as shown below) it prints the keys in increasing order.

This is what I want it to do, but I was wondering, for my own knowledge, why does this happen? Does it *auto sort* it in increasing order every time? As you can see in the dictionary above, the keys are clearly not in increasing order but the output below prints them in increasing order.

I'm just trying to gain a clear understanding, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

### Example

```
for i in a:
    print i
```

*Output*:

```
1
5
11
14
15
16
17
19
20
25
100
```

Comment: that's my main point in asking the question:  in that duplicate they use the function 'sorted'.  why would they use the function sorted if it does it every time?  does it sort it every time and why?

Comment: that comment was in response to a deleted comment.  why am i getting down voted?  i'm trying to learn about dictionaries and figured this would be the best place to ask.

Comment: my main question then is why in the 'duplicate' question do you need to put in the sorted?  doesn't it sort already?

Comment: no it does not sort the keys, try other examples and you will see for yourself

Comment: The order of keys is dependent on the implementation, and subject to change version-to-version. In your particular case, the keys happen to be sorted; never rely on this.

Comment: check out "the might dictionary "http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147

Comment: This is not a duplicate as suggested, the OP is asking why a.keys() turns out to be sorted, not how to iterate over a dict in sorted order.

Comment: @RussellBorogove  'dependent on the implementation' .. thats the part i'm trying to grasp.  so if you look at the dictionary i created, the keys are clearly not in increasing order, as expected.  when i loop through though it prints them out in increasing order.  so was it something beforehand in the implementation (creation) of this dictionary that would lead it sort like this?

Comment: The simple answer here is that "dependent on the implementation" means you should never rely on any particular order, and therefore you really don't need to understand how your current implementation happens to do ordering. If you really want to know exactly how some particular implementation does it, you have to tell us _which one_. Are you using CPython 3.4, or Jython 2.6, or …? And then, the best answer will really be "Here's the source code, with a nice long comment explaining things if you don't know C, come back if you have any questions", which is not a good format for SO.

Comment: Implementation means "which version of Python", not "creation of the dictionary".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integers in a dictionary are not always ordered by the key:

```
a = {2:0, 9:0}
print a.keys()  # [9, 2]
```

Python dictionaries are *[Hash Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)*, which are a special kind of array, where the *index* of the cell where you store the *value* is derived applying a special function (let's call it the `hash` function) on the *key*.
This way if you want to retrieve the *value* for a particular *key* you can compute again the `hash` function of the *key*, which will return the same result as before, obtaining the index where the *value* is stored.

The `hash` function converts *[most](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable)* types of data to an integer:

```
print hash(1)             # 1
print hash('hello')       # 840651671246116861
print hash((2,3))         # 3713082714463740756
```

Each type can define its own way to compute the *hash* and `int` *usually* returns itself:

```
print hash(1)             # 1
print hash(20)            # 20
print hash(1000)          # 1000
```

As you can see numbers get big soon, and we don't want to have an array with *840651671246116861* cells just to save the string `hello`.
To avoid the problem we can create an array with `n` elements and then use the remainder of the *hash* divided by `n` as the *index*.

For example if we want to find the index for `hello` in an array of *8* elements:

```
print hash('hello') % 8   # 5
```

So our dictionary will know that the *value* for the key `hello` is at index *8*. That's how dictionaries are implemented.

So, why `{2:0, 9:0}` is not ordered on keys? That's because python dictionaries are created with *8* elements, and grow as needed (more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented)).

Let's compute the index to store the data having `key = 2` and `key = 9` in a dictionary with `n = 8`:

```
print hash(2) % 8         # 2  [hash(2) = 2 and 2 % 8 = 2]
print hash(9) % 8         # 1  [hash(9) = 9 and 9 % 8 = 1]
```

This means that the *array* that contains the dictionary data will be:

```
| index | key | value |
|-------|-----|-------|
|   0   |     |       |
|   1   |  9  |   0   |
|   2   |  2  |   0   |
|   3   |     |       |
|   4   |     |       |
|   5   |     |       |
|   6   |     |       |
|   7   |     |       |
```

When iterating over it, the order will be the one presented in this representation, so `9` will be before `2`.

You can read more on the topic [here](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/).

Comment: One minor nit (to an otherwise great answer): the `int` type only uses itself for smallish integers. Try `hash(1<<100)`; on my 64-bit CPython 3.4, it's `549755813888`.

Comment: That's not an `int`, if you try `type(1<<100)` you will see that this is a `long`.

Comment: It's an `int` in Python 3.x. And even in 2.x, I'm pretty sure numbers within 1 bit of the `int` limit don't hash to themselves (although it's been a while, so that may be wrong). And of course `-1` never hashes to itself in any CPython, because it uses `-1` as a magic value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know why Python always puts the keys in sorted order… the answer is that it doesn't.

If you want to know why some particular version of some particular implementation of Python puts your particular keys in sorted order, the only real answer to that is the source code.

For CPython (the implementation you're probably using, if you don't know which one you're using), the source is in `Objects/dictobject.c`. It changed dramatically in 3.4, and before that in… I think 2.6/3.2, and there have been a few other less dramatic changes in history. So you will have to make sure to look up the version you actually care about. For 3.4, the source is at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Objects/dictobject.c. It's in C, but there are some great comments explaining what it's doing. If you really want to explore it, you could probably even port it to Python and run it under `pdb`.

One key issue that may not be obvious from reading the code, unless you understand hash tables, is that there are *two* "coincidences" here, not just one. First, some versions of CPython, when given a smallish dict constructed all at once, will put the keys in order by their hash values. Second, in all versions of CPython so far, small integers hash to themselves, so—unlike almost any other type—"in order by hash value" also means "in order by value".

Answer (score 1):

> everytime i loop through the dictionary (like shown below) it prints
>   the keys in increasing order.

This is just by chance. Dictionaries are **unordered** collection of objects, that are accessible by keys.

There is no "auto sort", or any other kind of sort.

Just think about it for one second - the whole point of setting your own keys is to be able to fetch by them, so it is not important for the keys to have an "order" - the point is that you know how to refer to each object, because you set its key.  This makes it very quick to fetch an object; because its very easy to find. There are no duplicate keys so internally the dictionary can be stored in an optimized way for fast access.

Compare this to a list which is ordered (and its order is guaranteed). In a list, the point is to fetch an object by its reference in the list - that is, by its position relative to other objects in the list.  Therefore, it makes sense to maintain order.

Tuples are similar to lists in that the are ordered.  One of the differences between tuples and lists is that tuples once set, cannot be changed (you can't "grow" or "shrink" a tuple). In order to modify a tuple, you have to create *another* tuple. So to "grow" a tuple, add two tuples together to get a *third, different* tuple. The original two tuples are unchanged.

If you want to know the technical details behind the implementation of dictionaries and how they work "under the hood" [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented) has a great answer with all the sundry information.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that it doesn't make sense for the keys to have an order. Many other languages have a dict-like class built on a sorted binary tree instead of a hash table, which makes it almost as fast to find a value (logarithmic instead of constant), but also lets you do things like find all keys within a certain range, or find the nearest key, etc. But otherwise, great explanation.

Comment: I tried to keep it as simple as possible, if we start down that path then soon we have to talk about `OrderedDict` and then its just all downhill from there :)

Comment: You say that keys showing up ordered just by chance, but the likelihood of that is tiny (you can add more [positive]keys), the sorted order still holds. I think there is more to it than that.

Comment: @Akavall: It's not _really_ just by chance, it's because of internal details of how your particular implementation works. But you should generally _pretend_ it's just by chance, because you can't do anything useful with the knowledge in any real program, or your assumptions break as soon as you upgrade Python or add 3 more keys or look at your computer funny.

Comment: Actually that is how it is implemented. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented) for internals on how dictionaries work, but keep in mind this is (as @abarnet pointed out) variable by your implementation.

Comment: @abarnert, I totally agree with that, but I think info about how "internal details of how your particular implementation works" is what OP is really asking about.

Comment: @Akavall: Except that he hasn't told us his particular implementation. I doubt he's expecting someone to iterate through every significant version of every Python implementation and explain them all in detail. I think he doesn't actually _know_ exactly what he's asking. And I think Burtan's answer tells him what he asked, and can hopefully lead him to realize that what he asked wasn't what he actually wanted to know. I think that's more than enough for an upvote.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: By the way, I like the rewritten version with "it's not important for them to have an order"; that whole paragraph is a great explanation of why dicts are hash tables without having to explain what a hash table is (and if he _does_ need that, enrico's answer covers that).

Answer (score -2):

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) says :

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique

Unlike Python lists or tuples, the key and value pairs in dict objects are not in any particular order. Although the key-value pairs are in a certain order when you instantiate the dictionary, by just calling the dict you can see they aren't stored in the same order.
Then if you want to sort them, just use the built-in [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) method

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I think I know why people did: The OP happened to run into one of those surprising cases where he _can't_ see your point, because they happen to be stored in sorted order. So, telling him to just look at the dict and see isn't helping this time.