# Built in python hash table implementation

Tags: python, hashtable

Is there a  built in implementation of hash table in python which finds the key based on value in O(c) time (c - constant). I guess dictionaries in python finds the key just by iterating through the values.

Comment: Python dictionary **is** a hash table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented

Comment: What makes you think Python dictionaries are O(n)? Why would that make sense?

Comment: That was a terrible guess, which a small amount of research could have disproved.

Answer (score 2):

Python's `dict` **is** a hash-table (see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented))

And from [Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys):

> Python's dictionary implementation reduces the average complexity of dictionary lookups to O(1) by requiring that key objects provide a "hash" function