# how many space assigned for empty dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

If we create an empty dictionary, like: `idict = {}`, how many spaces are assigned for this dictionary ? I know for the list, if we initialize a list like `ilist = []`, it will always over-allocate the size, first is 4 space, then 8.
What about a dictionary ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented

Comment: If we want to check the duplicate of the ASCII characters, allocate list with 256 size is cheaper or allocate a dictionary is cheaper ?

Comment: To check duplicates a set seems more appropriate since checking membership is a typical basic operation for a set.

Answer (score 2):

Well, dictionaries don't store the actual string inside them, it works a bit like C/C++ pointers, so you only get a constant overhead in the dictionary for every element.

Testing against

```
import sys
x = {}
sys.getsizeof(x)
```

The dictionary itself consists of a number of buckets, each containing:

- the hash code of the object currently stored (that is not predictable
  from the position of the bucket due to the collision resolution
  strategy used)
- a pointer to the key object a pointer to the value
- object in total at least 12 bytes on 32bit and 24 bytes on 64bit.

The dictionary starts out with 8 empty buckets and is resized by doubling the number of entries whenever its capacity is reached (currently (2n+1)/3).

Comment: *"The dictionary starts out with 8 empty buckets and is resized by doubling the number of entries whenever its capacity is reached."* Sort of. In fact they grow by a calculated amount when they are about 2/3 full. Here you can see the full explanation https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/dictobject.c#l258

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it actually works like `associative map` in `C++`..If you have ever used `C++` then..If you see the source code of Python Interpreter, you will see that it uses your heap memory section to store data to two type & use pointers to point one data to other exactly like `map` works in `C++`. In my system it is 280.. Now as @Navneet said you can use sys.getsizeof to calculate the size. But remember that it is system specific & hence your system might not give you 280bytes. Understand that if it is 280bytes, it means it uses a delicate thread of several associative pointers to store an point to the data structure