# Dictionary output from for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I just started with the Python course from codecademy. I am trying to return the dic values in the order as they are in the dictionary.

```
residents = {'Puffin' : 104, 'Sloth' : 105, 'Burmese Python' : 106}


res = residents.values()
count = 0
for element in res:
    print res[count]
    count += 1
```

The output I received:
105
104
106

From this I get that i do not fully understand how the for-loop or dictionary works, I was expecting to get 104 105 106 as output. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition in Python. If you want to keep order, use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: As an alternative you can use the `OrderedDict`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: A plain dictionary is very fast to access & efficient in memory use, but that power comes at a price. BTW, your `for` loop is a bit odd. You don't need `count`, you can just do `for element in res:` `print element`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered in Python. Many a time I tried running loops over them and expected output in the same order as I gave it the input but it didn't work. So I guess, it's no fault of the `for loop`.

As Maroun suggests in the comments, you should be using `OrderedDict` for that.

Comment: Well if he wants 104, 105, 106 then he can just sort the values numerically too.

Comment: The question feels more about `why` to the dictionary behavior than `how` to get a sorted output..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the keys nor associated values from a dict in the order you put them there. The order you get them seems to be random.

If you want an ordered dict please use collections.OrderedDict or store the keys in a list an work with both: a list keeping the keys in the ordered they were added to dict and the actual dict.

Comment: I recommend against manually maintaining a list of keys, as this requires unnecessary administration that is done for you in OrderedDict. That's what it's for.

Comment: The order seems random because a `dict` is implemented as a [hash table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented).