# Dictionary order in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Everywhere I search, they say python dictionary's doesn't have any order.
When I run code 1 each time shows a different output (random order). But when I run code 2 it always shows the same sorted output. Why is the dictionary ordered in the second snippet?

```
   #code 1

    d = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
    for a, b in d.items():
        print(a, b)
   #code 2 

    d = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}
    for a, b in d.items():
        print(a, b)
```

**Outputs**

code 1:

```
four 4
two 2
three 3
one 1
```

code 1 again:

```
three 3
one 1
two 2
four 4
```

code 2 (always):

```
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's related to how hash randomisation is applied. Quoting [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) (emphasis mine):

> By default, the `__hash__()` values of **str**, **bytes** and **datetime**
>   objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value. Although they
>   remain constant within an individual Python process, they are not
>   predictable between repeated invocations of Python.

For each subsequent run, your strings (keys in snippet 1) are hashed with different salt value - therefore hash value is also changed. Hash values determine ordering.

For `int` type, hash function never changes - in fact hash is always equal to integer value.

```
assert hash(42) == 42
```

If hashing function never changes, there is no change in ordering in subsequent runs.

For details in how Python dictionaries are implemented, you may refer to [How are Python's Built In Dictionaries Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented).

Comment: Hash is not always identity on integers.  `-1` hashes to `-2` and hash of really big integers has to come down too e.g. `hash(10**20)`

Answer (score 0):

Not anymore: from Python 3.6 onwards, the standard `dict` type maintains insertion order by default, see the What's New in Python 3.6 documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-compactdict).

Python 3.7 elevated this implementation detail to a *language specification*, so  it is now mandatory that `dict` preserves order Python 3.7+

(via [@Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/575530), and the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping))