# Limitation on dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I understand that Python uses `hash` method to lookup the keys in the dictionary but if the dictionary grows too large and the key do no longer fit in the hashing result range (*collision*), how would python handle it ?

how do we handle dictionaries with billions of record(*too many keys which will make collision occur at high rate*), should we change the hashing function if yes, how to do it ?

Comment: [PyCon 2010: The Mighty Dictionary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68). This is all you need to know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented