# Running time of in dict compare to ==

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

In an exam, I was asked which of the following function is most likely to run faster:

```
def f1():
    a = []
    for j in range(100000): a.append(j*j)
    for j in range(100000):
        if 99999*j == a[j]:
            print("yes")

def f3():
    d = {}
    for j in range(100000): d[j] = j*j
    for j in range(100000):
        if 99999*j in d:
            print("yes")
```

It's obvious that both `in` and `==` are O(1).

But still, I was surprise to see that the `f1` runs faster.

Any explanation  will be appreciated.

Comment: The two pieces of code do different things altogether.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 1):

The *constant* costs are different. Just because two algorithms are O(1) does not make them equivalent. For one, dictionaries are only O(1) *on average*, while list lookup is O(1), always.

You need analyse the differences, but you are making a wrong assumption here. `f1` looks up an element by index in list, then tests for equality. The `f2` tests an element in a dictionary. However, a dictionary membership test which involves hashing **and a test for equality** (if there is an object at that location).

So the real difference here is that of hashing versus a list lookup. And the list lookup wins as its cost is still O(1), but hashing can be O(N), based on the size of the object being hashed. The difference explains the timings you see:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> a = [j * j for j in range(100000)]
>>> timeit.timeit('a[5000]', 'from __main__ import a', number=10**7)
0.26793562099919654
>>> timeit.timeit('_h(5000)', '_h = hash', number=10**7)
0.4080043680005474
```

The actual cost of hashing is normally averaged out over all dictionary membership lookups; together with the possible worst-case scenario of O(N) lookups for dictionaries, that makes dictionary lookups only *average* O(1). List lookups on the other hand are always O(1).

Answer (score 0):

> It's obvious that both in and == are O(1).

‒ No, it's not.

Complexity of in for dicts and sets is average O(1) and worst (with a lot of collisions) up to O(N). 
For better understanding of how does hash tables, dicts, sets and so on work, please read this - [How are Python's Built In Dictionaries Implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented)