# In Python Dictionaries, how does ( (j*5)+1 ) % 2**i cycle through all 2**i

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, linear-probing

I am researching how python implements dictionaries.   One of the equations in the python dictionary implementation relates the pseudo random probing for an empty dictionary slot using the equation

```
j = ((j*5) + 1) % 2**i
```

which is explained [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c#l89).

I have read this question, [How are Python's Built In Dictionaries Implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented), and basically understand how dictionaries are implemented.

What I don't understand is why/how the equation:

```
j = ((j*5) + 1) % 2**i
```

cycles through all the remainders of  `2**i`.    For instance,  if `i = 3` for a total starting size of 8.  `j` goes through the cycle:

```
0
1
6
7
4
5
2
3
0
```

if the starting size is 16, it would go through the cycle:

```
0 1 6 15 12 13 2 11 8 9 14 7 4 5 10 3 0
```

This is very useful for probing all the slots in the dictionary.  **But why does it work ?**   Why does  `j = ((j*5)+1)` work but not `j = ((j*6)+1)`  or `j = ((j*3)+1)`  both of which get stuck in smaller cycles.

I am hoping to get a more intuitive understanding of this than *the equation just works and that's why they used it*.

Comment: Because 5 is co-prime with 2^i, so the [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) is 5 * 2^i.

Comment: A few lines above your quote: "see any text on random-number generation for proof" :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth by that argument, then (j*3)+1 should also work.

Comment: Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming: Volume 2" has an extensive treatment of similar problems that you may find helpful.

Comment: This is only tangentially a Python question, a dictionary question, or even a programming question at all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the same principle that pseudo-random number generators use, as Jasper hinted at, namely [linear congruential generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). A linear congruential generator is a sequence that follows the relationship `X_(n+1) = (a * X_n + c) mod m`. From the wiki page,

> The period of a general LCG is at most m, and for some choices of factor a much less than that. The LCG will have a full period for all seed values if and only if:
>
> 1. `m` and `c` are relatively prime.
> 2. `a - 1` is divisible by all prime factors of `m`.
> 3. `a - 1` is divisible by 4 if `m` is divisible by `4`.

It's clear to see that 5 is the smallest `a` to satisfy these requirements, namely

1. 2^i and 1 are relatively prime.
2. 4 is divisible by 2.
3. 4 is divisible by 4.

Also interestingly, 5 is not the only number that satisfies these conditions. 9 will also work. Taking `m` to be 16, using `j=(9*j+1)%16` yields

```
0 1 10 11 4 5 14 15 8 9 2 3 12 13 6 7
```

The proof for these three conditions can be found in [the original Hull-Dobell paper](http://chagall.med.cornell.edu/BioinfoCourse/PDFs/Lecture4/random_number_generator.pdf) on page 5, along with a bunch of other PRNG-related theorems that also may be of interest.

Comment: Don't want to be pedantic but I think it's *pseudo random* not *random*;)

Comment: It can't be "if and only if" in the statement of the theorem; e.g. taking `c = 0` and `a` to be a primitive root modulo 2^i will result in a full period, but `0` isn't coprime with `m`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yeah, I was just wondering about that as well. It looks like the original paper suggests sufficiency, however the "if and only if" comes from the Knuth citation. Knuth also enforces a nonzero `c`, so I think the wiki summarization is just incomplete for this special case. I'll fix the wiki page...

Comment: @kevmo314   Thanks for the response.  I accepted this as the right answer, but I'm not sure I completely understand every situation.   For instance, with  a = 7,  c = 1,  m =13  I get a period length of 12 instead of 13, but that appears to satisfy all 3 requirements.    On the other hand, with a = 7, c=1, m = 18 it works perfectly and I get a period length of 18 as expected

Comment: I suppose having m = 13 in my previous comment might not satisfy condition 2 since 13 has no prime factors  (since it is itself prime)

Comment: Knuth btw. also mentions that *“when m is the product of distinct primes, only a = 1 will produce the full period”*, so that should give you an idea on what not to choose for `m` :)

Comment: @FairlyNerdy Your followup is correct, 13's prime factors include 13, which 6 is not divisible by. If `m` is composed of distinct prime factors, then the only solution will be a = 1, as @poke notes.