# How to check if elements(coordinates) of a set form a continous shape?

Tags: python, set, tuples

I am trying to write a function that gets a set of tuples as parameter, and checks if given characters form a continuous shape in an NxN grid. Tuples are the indexes of characters in the lists that form the grid. The shape is continuous if there is a character directly below, above or to the sides of another character.

```
continuous             not continous         not continous
  xxxxx                   xxxxx                 ooxxx   
  xxoox                   xxoox                 xxxxx
  xxxoo                   ooxxx                 xxoox 
  xxxoo                   oxxxx                 xxoox
  xxxxo                   xoxxx                 xxxxx
```

========================

```
    def connected(characters):
        result = True
        for i in characters:
            if (i[0]+1, i[1]) in characters or (i[0]-1, i[1]) in characters or (i[0], i[1]+1) in characters or (i[0], i[1]-1) in characters:
                result = True
                characters.discard(i)
            else:
                result = False
                return result
        return result

>>>connected({(1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (0, 3), (1, 1)})
```

would form this shape, thus it wouldn't be continuous but my code thinks it is.

```
xxxo
xoxo
xoxo
xxxx
```

This works for the most time, but doesn't work when given characters form two separate continuous shapes like the 2nd wrong example I gave above. I tried to solve this problem by removing each tuple after it was checked but I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled6/venv/1.py", line 47, in <module>
    connected({(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)})
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled6/venv/1.py", line 15, in connected
    for i in grid:
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

error. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Don't change the size of the set during iteration then! Use a new set.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: @arthionne Add that to your post, it's practically impossible to read as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more info on the error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38423075. Basically, you have to iterate over a copy of a set if you want to modifiy this set in the loop.

Apart from that, there is a flaw in your algorithm.

If you don't discard the current character, you check only if every character has a neighbor. This will be ok:

```
xxxxx
xoxox
xoxox
xxxxx
```

But if you discard the current character, you may have suprises:

```
 xxx            xxx
 xox <- cur     x x <- discarded
 xox            xox <- has no neighbor!
 xxx            xxx
```

The classic algorithm is based on a tree traversal: start from any not and traverse all the directly linked nodes. If all nodes where seen, the graph is connected.

I use a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) here, but you can use a [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) if you want:

```
def connected(characters):
    seen = set()
    stack = [next(iter(characters))] if characters else []
    while stack:
        c = stack.pop()
        seen.add(c)
        for other_c in [(c[0]+1, c[1]), (c[0]-1, c[1]), (c[0], c[1]+1), (c[0], c[1]-1)]:
            if other_c not in seen and other_c in characters:
                stack.append(other_c)

    return not (characters - seen)

print(connected({(1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (0, 3), (1, 1)}))
# False
print(connected({(1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (0, 3), (1, 1), (1, 2)}))
# True
```