# Collisions in dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap, collision

I have a question about collisions in 'Dict' structure in Python. 
Search, insertion and deletion in 'Dict' structure (built in Python) is about O(1) time complexity on **average**. We all know this is becuase collisions, that might happen if the hash function maps some objects (according to their keys) to the same place in the dictionary. 
My question:
I am going to insert to the Dictionay (built in Python) the keys: **"a","b","c",...,"z"**. Is there **any** possibility to have a collision in the hash mapping with these keys? Will it be for sure O(1) time complxity [worst case] becuase where will not be collisions? Who can ensure to me that collisions with these keys will not happen? How Python's hash function works?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are Python's Built In Dictionaries Implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented)

Comment: You're inserting a whopping 26 keys into your dict and are worried about time complexity? Why?

Comment: @Rawing: I had an exam in university. I need to be sure that the program works on O(1) time complexity WORST CASE. I need to prove my lecturer that in this case I won't have any collision. I dont know how to prove it. Please help me :P

Comment: This is a terrible exam question. Whether or not a hash collision occurs depends on the hash function used, __and__ the exact implementation of the dict. While python's built-in `hash` produces a different hash for each character a-z (i.e. there are no collisions), if the dict internally only has 2 buckets and computes `hash(...)%2`, there are __still__ going to be collisions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for

http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/

Comment: That looks obsolete.