# What is the time complexity of dictionary on all operation with tuple value as its key in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I am learning Python and wondering what would be the time complexity of dictionary on all operation(Copy[2], Get Item, Set Item[1], Delete Item, Iteration[2]).
If I use tuple values as a key in the dictionary. Can someone please throw some light ?

Here's the sample code.

```
keys = ("Name", "age", "height")

dog = {keys[0]: "labrador", keys[1]: 2, keys[2]: 3}
```

Comment: Can you give an example with code of one of these operations on the dictionary you have shown?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner and I have never tried to calculate the time complexity in Python, [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) what I got the table of time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity):

Except copy or iteration, dict have a complexity of O(1) or worse case O(n).

For copy or iteration, it's logical that it is O(n) as there is n elements that you can access in O(1) complexity.

As commented by Laurent, all dictionnary are "stored" based on the hash of the key ([link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-time-complexity-of-checking-if-a-key-is-in-a-dictionary-in-Python)). In some cases, it can happens that 2 keys have the same hash (collision). In such cases, I imagine, it end up in the "Amortized Worst Case" as it's gonna check all keys as is and not the hash. You can also find more information about the build of dictionnaries on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented).

In addition, for copy and iterations, you should consider the biggest n reach in the dictionnary. If you fill 10000 entries then remove 9990 and do a copy, you should consider 10000 elements and not 10.

**EDIT 1**: Test times based on key time

You can test the time based on key type with following code :

```
import timeit

def f1():
    a = {}
    for i in range(1000):
        a[i] = i
    return a

def f2():
    a = {}
    for i in range(1000):
        a[str(i)] = i
    return a

def f3():
    a = {}
    for i in range(1000):
        a[(i, i)] = i
    return a

def f4():
    a = {}
    for i in range(1000):
        a[(str(i), str(i))] = i
    return a

print(timeit.timeit("f1()", number = 1000, setup="from __main__ import f1")) # => 0.0541156338055877
print(timeit.timeit("f2()", number = 1000, setup="from __main__ import f2")) # => 0.2492961917066741
print(timeit.timeit("f3()", number = 1000, setup="from __main__ import f3")) # => 0.09082684668080204
print(timeit.timeit("f4()", number = 1000, setup="from __main__ import f4")) # => 0.4479192082498416
```

Unfortunately, you cannot compare them 1 by 1 as f2 and f4 use str() function which slow down the function but you can at least see that tuple is slower than simple string or integer. Nevertheless you can estimate with the following code the time used to convert to str()

```
def f5():
    for i in range(1000):
        str(i)

print(timeit.timeit("f5()", number = 1000, setup="from __main__ import f5"))
```

And this is evaluate to 0.1645s. Without this time is f2 and twice in f4 you have :

```
0.08614475546254619s for f2
0.12553885821459693s for f3
```

This gives you some idea about the time to create dict based on the key style. You can do the same to test time access but if hashes doesn't collide, time should be the same no matter the key style.

You can also take a look to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTZJLJ3Gm6Q&t=352s) I found tonight

I hope it helps,

Comment: Not agree, the complexity is based on hash values, not on values themselves. So, string keys are not better than tuple.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this is how I understand the following sentence : "Note that there is a fast-path for dicts that (in practice) only deal with str keys; this doesn't affect the algorithmic complexity, but it can significantly affect the constant factors: how quickly a typical program finishes."

Comment: @NicolasM. and Laurent LAPORTE So is there any difference I can see in [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) dict table if I use tuple values as key to the dict or it will remain the same ?.

Comment: As Laurent highlighted, if you don't have collisions between 2 hashes, the speed should be the same. Nevertheless, there is a "quick path" for string keys only which has been built to make it a bit faster than other types.

Comment: @NicolasM. Ok, so what would be the conclusion for this question? Correct me if I'm wrong, At the end string data goes to the hash table no matter from where it comes from, In this question scenario dictionary is getting key as a string no matter from where that coming from, so using tuple values as key to the dictionary will not affect default time complexity of the tuple that's on the official document [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: I've edited the answer with tests instead of anly theorical assumptions. And now I'm a bit lost if I compare results to documentations