# Print unsorted dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I want to print out the unsorted dictionary, but it came out sorted.

This is the code I use (Version 2.7.5 Linux):

```
# id and name array are not the actual input. It is just a sample input. (So no hard-coding please) 
# More importantly, I just want to figure out how to have the unsorted dictionary.

id = [1 ,4, 2] 
name = ["John" , "Mary", "Alice"]
my_dict = {}

for x in range(len(id)):
    my_dict[id[x]] = name[x]

for key, val in my_dict.items():
    print(key, val)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
(1, "John")
(4, "Mary")
(2, "Alice")
```

**Actual Output:**

```
(1, "John")
(2, "Alice")
(4, "Mary")
```

Comment: dictionary in python is never sorted. what you are seeing is just something that happened by chance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327311/how-are-pythons-built-in-dictionaries-implemented

Comment: then when i do key_list = list(my_dict.keys()). i expect to see key_list as [1 , 4 , 2 ] but it returned me with [1, 2 , 4].

Comment: pls refer to the link that i have shared. it depends on hashing

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** sorted. In Python 2.7 (and pre-3.7 releases) dictionaries are *unordered*; meaning them they can be stored in any order. In your test, by coincidence, they are stored in such a way. If you try the same test using Python 3.7 you will see your expected result.

If you want to keep the creation order on Python 2.7, use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.