# Complexity of iterating over a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

This is a fairly simple question I have not been able to find an answer for.
If I have a dictionary, what is the complexity of iterating over it?

In other words, what is the time complexity of a dictionary traversal such as `for key in my_dict: print(key)`?

My naive understanding is that since dictionaries in Python are hashmaps, we would need to iterate over all possible hash values of the dictionary.

That seems like quite an overkill, but maybe is fine since the dictionary gets progressively bigger as we add elements, so we amortize the cost by always having a dictionary which is almost full up to a constant load factor?

Comment: iterating is just `O(n)`. no hashing is involved when you iterate on the keys/items

Comment: Let's say you have *n* keys in your dictionary and you need to iterate through *n* keys printing each of the keys i.e takes `O(n)`.

Comment: In dictionaries *values* are indexed by *keys* so `dict[key]` takes `O(1)` .

Comment: … unless there are collisions. It can take up to `O(n)` if all keys have the same hash. But it's very unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In most cases**, iterating over a dictionary takes O(n) time in total, or on average O(1) time per element, where n is the number of items in the dictionary.

There are various different versions of Python's dictionary data structure, depending on which version of Python you're using, but all of them are some kind of [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). A hashtable either has an array of key/value pairs, or an array of keys and a parallel array of values. **Usually**, a fixed proportion (known as the [load factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Key_statistics)) of the array will contain dictionary items, with the rest of the spaces remaining empty, so the length of the array you need to iterate over is a fixed constant times the number of dictionary items. This means you can iterate in O(n) time.

[In recent versions of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44509302/12299000), the dictionary data structure's array simply holds indices to each item in another array, where the items in the other array are kept in insertion order. This additional array can be used to iterate over the dictionary in insertion order, still in O(n) time, but without having to skip over unused spaces in the lookup array.

Note that either way, we do not actually need to compute the hashes of any keys in order to iterate over the dictionary's items.

---

All of that said, there are **some cases** where iterating over a dictionary can take more than O(n) time. The reason for this is that although the capacity of the hashtable is enlarged when necessary to insert more items, it is *not* shrunk when items are removed. (Thanks to @HeapOverflow for pointing this out in the comments.)

If many items have been removed, then the proportion of dictionary items to the array capacity could be much smaller than the load factor. In that case, the array can be larger than a fixed constant times the number of items, so iterating takes more than O(n) time.

This is even true for the data structure used in more recent versions, which iterates using the additional array instead of the lookup array. When items are removed, they are simply replaced with `NULL` ([CPython source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d5bf568eaa5059402ccce9ba5a366986ba27c8a/Objects/dictobject.c#L1570)); presumably this is done to allow removal in O(1) time while maintaining insertion order. Consequently, the additional array can also be longer than O(n) if many items are removed.

In most applications it is not common to remove a lot of items from a dictionary; if you need to do this and are concerned about iterating over those dictionaries efficiently, consider instead building a new dictionary using just the keys you need to keep, instead of removing them from the existing dictionary.

Comment: @HeapOverflow The number of dictionary items. I thought that was clear enough, but I suppose someone could confuse it with the length of the underlying array, so I've edited.

Comment: Yeah, that's precisely why I asked. Because it's *not* always a fixed portion that actually contains items. I can easily produce a dictionary with **0** items that takes much longer to iterate than one with 9999 items: https://repl.it/repls/ShockedFaintScreencast

Comment: @HeapOverflow Good catch, thank you, and I've edited. I'm a little surprised that the same behaviour occurs for the "compact dict", since the deletion algorithm could check e.g. whether it's 75%-full of NULLs and reallocate/re-index if so. That would give deletion an O(1) amortized cost, like insertion, but it would guarantee O(n) iteration. I guess optimising for the case where lots of items are deleted was not the goal.

Comment: @HeapOverflow re: `dict.clear` - I did the foolish thing of trying to derive it by reading the source instead of testing. It didn't look like it was re-allocating the array, but I guess I missed something. Thanks again.

Comment: I just remembered [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) and saw it's actually mentioned in note [2].